# Linking c++ dylib in unity gives undefined symbol error

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, bind, dylib

## What I want to do

- I want to use dylib (C header library) from unity.
- Target is iOS

## What I did.

- dylib in `Assets/Plugins/iOS`.
- Use `__Internal` for iOS when routing dylib

```cs
        #if (UNITY_IPHONE && !UNITY_EDITOR) || (UNITY_WEBGL && !UNITY_EDITOR)
            public const String __DllName="__Internal";
        #else
            const string __DllName = "voicevox_core";
        #endif
```

## Error

- I got the following error (all functions in dylib are displayed)

```
undefined synbol [function name]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `__Internal` looked for a static library, and since the library I use is `dylib`, I made the mistake of making it `__Internal`. So I changed `__Internal` to the name of the library and it works fine.